# Without objection

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

A word that can describe doing something without objecting.

Shouldn't connote being unhappy with the task you have been asked to carry out, either completely neutral sentiment or slightly positive.

> His ______ compliance with her strict instructions

Comment: unconditional...

Comment: His complacent compliance.

Answer (score 4):

Complying without objecting would be described by **acquiescence** (passive acceptance):

> His acquiescence to her strict instructions

Although technically, that would mean agreeing to them, not necessarily complying with them.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquiescence

Comment: I've used acquiescence already in the passage I'm writing, is there a "synonym" of acquiescence comprised of two words where the first would fit the situation described above?

Comment: +1 though, this is a good answer and exactly what I have in mind

Comment: If you already used acquiesce and are further describing such action, just using compliance is probably fine.

Answer (score 4):

***Willing*** - *Having a ready will; disposed to consent or comply; ready to do (what is specified or implied) without reluctance, having no objection, ‘not disposed to refuse’ (Johnson); spec. disposed to do what is required, ready to be of use or service.*(OED)

His ***willing*** compliance with her strict instructions.

Comment: I was just going to suggest "consensual", but willing is better.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are looking for **unquestioning**.

> His *unquestioning* compliance with her strict instructions

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unquestioning

> Definition of unquestioning
>
> not questioning :  not expressing or marked by doubt or hesitation
>
> *unquestioning obedience*; *unquestioning loyalty*

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider ***tacit***, defined by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tacit) as:

> :  implied or indicated (as by an act or by silence) but not actually expressed <tacit consent> <tacit admission of guilt>

Answer (score 2):

The word ***ready***, in the sense of *readily or willingly given*, seems to fit:

"His [**ready**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ready)  compliance with her strict instructions."

> 3:  displayed [readily](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/readily) and spontaneously

*Readily* has this definition:

> a :  without hesitating :  willingly "readily accepted advice"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ***quiet*** would suffice:

> His quiet compliance with her strict instructions

> 1.1 (of a place, period of time, or situation) without much activity, disturbance, or excitement.
>
> [[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quiet)]

It doesn't necessarily connote unhappiness, merely an acceptance and lack of any comment at all, whether in dissent or approbation.

It is quite likely, however, that the word *compliance* is indicative of duress, and consequently **any** adjective would be construed in that light.

Answer (score 1):

**"peaceful"** comes to mind.

"His peaceful compliance with her strict instructions" sounds completely neutral or slightly positive depending on context.

> - [peaceful](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peaceful) - untroubled by conflict, agitation, or commotion :  quiet, tranquil.
>
> The feeling … that we as neighbors could settle any disputes in peaceful fashion — F. D. Roosevelt

Answer (score 0):

try the word ["unresisting"](https://www.wordnik.com/words/unresisting):

> Not making resistance; not opposing; submissive; humble.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider ***nonchalant***.

> His ***nonchalant*** compliance with her strict instructions...

ODO:

> **[nonchalant](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nonchalant)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> (of a person or manner) feeling or appearing casually calm and
>   relaxed; not displaying anxiety, interest, or enthusiasm.
>
> ‘The men swore again, wondering how Tori could be so nonchalant when
>   so many things were going wrong.’